# Facebook proxy email not arriving -- do I need permissions?

Tags: facebook

I'm building a website that allows user to connect using Facebook Connect. So far I'm able to log the user in and fetch data about them (name, email, pic, etc.). If I fetch the email (using Users.getInfo) I get a proxied email (apps+blahblah@facebook.com), which is absolutely great. Problem is, that email doesn't work. I've tried sending an email to it and I never received it. There are two reasons I see that could cause this:

1. I don't have enough permissions. Ok, I can understand that, but if I don't have enough permissions then why are they returning an email at all?
2. The email has to be somehow sent from the application itself (I've tried sending it from my Gmail account) -- but how would Facebook know that the email is coming from the application?

So which is it? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recently been looking into this as well.

I did find some guidelines on http://www.insidefacebook.com/2010/01/15/facebook-platform-email-sharing-api-proxy-email-service-going-live-in-5-days/

here is the most important part:
Emails you send must clearly indicate that they are from you and must not appear to be from Facebook or anyone else. For example, you must not include Facebook logos or brand assets in your emails, and you must not mention Facebook in the subject line, “from” line, or body header. All emails to users must originate from the same domain, and you must provide us with the name of that domain in the Facebook Developer application used to manage your application.

I have already found that if you do not have the address in the from as @facebookappmail.com
might even have to be appname@facebookappmail.com the emails will bounce. So sending from your gmail will not work, the "blah blah blah" in the proxy contains the application information of the application that had the permissions to get that email.